# Can I run SqlQuery on a View?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

So I have this query:

```
  var retval = db.v_AViewOfJoinedTables.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.v_AViewOfJoinedTables WHERE @filter = '@value';", 
                                          new SqlParameter("@filter", columnname), 
                                          new SqlParameter("@value", value)).ToList();
```

But I'm not getting any result. If I run this query through SSMS, it returns data. I know if I use a table instead that it works. So can SqlQuery only work on tables or is something wrong my query or code?

UPDATED CODE:

```
        SqlCommandBuilder scb = new SqlCommandBuilder();
        string columnname = userNameFilterType;
        string escapedColumnName = scb.QuoteIdentifier(columnname);
        string sqlQuery = String.Format("SELECT * FROM dbo.v_AViewOfJoinedTables WHERE {0} = '@username';", escapedColumnName);
        var retval = db.v_AViewOfJoinedTables.SqlQuery(sqlQuery, new SqlParameter("username", currentUser)).ToList();
        return retval.AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the view.  You can't use SQL parameters for table or column names.

```
... where @filter = ...
```

That won't work.  It *must* be text.  Just use string interpolation to insert it:

```
var retval = db.v_AViewOfJoinedTables.SqlQuery($"SELECT * FROM dbo.v_AViewOfJoinedTables WHERE {columnname} = @value;",
    new SqlParameter("@value", value)).ToList();
```

The SQL Execution Engine will cache the execution plan of queries you run, but it can't do that if the query *itself* changes.  The plan might change depending on the column name, for instance.  So, SQL parameters will only ever work as values supplied to the query.

You also need to remove the single quotes around `@value`.  The SQL Server provider will handle the quote insertion for you.

Comment: Does the `$` do something? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: Yes, it's the new string interpolation operator from C# 6.  It's effectively `String.Format(...)`

Comment: Well for whatever reason that's not working either. I didn't use `$`. I used regular `String.Format`. I'll update my code above. There must be a setting I'm missing or something.

Comment: "it doesn't work" doesn't provide useful diagnostic information.  Are you catching an exception?  Try removing the single quotes from around `@value`

Comment: You do well with non-useful diagnostic information. :) Actually there was no exception it just wasn't returning any data. But removing the quotes from around `@value` worked. Does the SqlParameter add the quotes on its own?

Comment: It *can*, depending on the database provider.  For SQL Server it definitely does.  I don't know about other providers.  I'll add the quote removal to my answer.